# call presentModalViewController in block completion

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, block

in my code i'm using this class:

https://github.com/gpambrozio/BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets

and i want call a presentModalViewController when i press the button in the dialog view in this way:

```
BlockAlertView *alert = [BlockAlertView alertWithTitle:@"Example" message:@"Text"];
[alert setDestructiveButtonWithTitle:@"Ok" block:^{
FirstView *firstView = [[FirstView alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstView" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:firstView animated:YES];
}];
[alert show];
```

but the app freeze, and after a minute open the view, so my question is how i can presentemodalviewcontroller in block completion?

Comment: Code works for me. I downloaded the BlockAlerts demo project and put your code into `viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated`. It worked fine. It must be something else you're doing. How about paste the entire class?

Comment: Is the block executing on the main thread?

Answer (score 0):

Actually have some mistakes, first, when you instanciate some class / variable inside a block they responde and have life cycle just inside that block.
So your block you run in another thread and this is the cause, and with this way you probably will cause retain cycle that its very bad situation for you app, change for something like this:

```
BlockAlertView *alert = [BlockAlertView alertWithTitle:@"Example" message:@"Text"];
FirstView *firstView = [[FirstView alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstView" bundle:nil];
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
[alert setDestructiveButtonWithTitle:@"Ok" block:^{

[weakSelf presentModalViewController: weakSelf.firstView animated:YES];
}];
[alert show];
```

Doing this, using __weak typeof we created a weak reference that prevent blocks from create strong reference cycle *(its good to read about) and now we make sure that will use our view that are instantiated for present new modal view.

Any doubt fill free for ask :)